# How to set laravel rate limiter per day?

Tags: laravel, throttling, rate-limiting

Laravel 8 rate limiter supports per minute rate limiting. I need to set a rate limit per day. any workarounds?

Update:

`Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit` class has `perDay` method.

Answer (score 5):

you can use the [perDay](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Cache/RateLimiting/Limit.html#method_perDay) method by changing in `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`.

```
 protected function configureRateLimiting()
    {
        RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perDay(60)->by(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip());
        });
    }
```

Comment: @Anil welcome brother and accept my answer